# How can we translate "Don't be a wuss (or cry-baby)" into German?

Tags: translation, idiom, english-to-german

I'd like to know how should we translate

> "Don't be a wuss (or cry-baby)"

into German? Which of [these options](http://www.dict.cc/?s=wuss&=DEEN&=) (*Weichei, Feigling, Schlappschwanz, Waschlappen, Memme, Schwächling, Lulu*) would be the correct one?

Comment: As trivial translation request off topic.

Comment: Agree to @userunknown Two minutes using google would answer the question, tops.

Comment: Non-trivial translation requests are on topic.

Comment: @Takkat Imho *Sei keine Memme* fits best. Alternatively *Sei kein Weichei* or *Was bist du für ein Schlappschwanz?*. If you're looking for the latter, it is on-topic, but if you're looking for a general translation (and he does), you find both Memme and Weichei, without doubt. *Reiß dich zusammen* is a better translation for [*Get a grip*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+a+grip) or [*Get hold of yourself*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+hold+of) or [*Pull yourself together*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+together)

Comment: @Takkat Let me add, however, it is possible to translate *Don't be a wuss* as *Reiß dich zusammen*, of course. But it is not the primary choosing. Knut gave the best answer. It is *Sei keine Memme* and perhaps *Reiß dich zusammen*. And for this reason, I maintain. (Even if not, I can't unvote ;p)

Comment: @Takkat: There is no context given to make a finer suggestion. Just list the leo results, and you have a valid answer.

Comment: It is trivial: 10 seconds to get it translated via google translator: https://translate.google.at/?hl=de&tab=wT#en/de/Don't%20be%20a%20wuss

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Eigentlich ist solche Übersetzung wegen der doppelten Verneinung falsch. Aber ich stimme dir zu und gebe der Frage einen **-1** (wenn man die offen lassen will, kostet einem das Edit Zeit).

Comment: @c.p. Lustigerweise ist im bairisch-österreichischen Dialekt die doppelte Verneinung oft »richtig« (im Sinne von *alle benutzen es*)

Comment: When I worked in Bavaria, the colleagues used "Warmduscher" - one who showers in warm water, as a term of disparagement,

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: I'm not sure whether you were seeing a different result at the time, but the current output of "trivially" asking Google Translate is "Sei kein Wuss."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Du hast recht. Der Google Übersetzer hat in den letzten vier Jahren massiv an Qualität zugelegt, aber in diesem speziellen Fall liefert er jetzt ein schlechteres Ergebnis als vor 4 Jahren.

Answer (score 13):

I would use:

> Sei keine Memme

You can find more words in [leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=wuss).

Perhaps you could also use:

> Reiß dich zusammen (Pull yourself together!)

Answer (score 8):

The word `Weichei` is the "mother" of all decending `Weicheiwörter`.

A couple of years ago, there was quite some hype about these words and people came up with more and more synonyms for Weichei, as [this textfile](http://www.weichei.de/docs/weiche_synonyme.txt) shows.

I guess you have expressions like that in other languages as well, but 3000 is really impressive, even though many of them are really far-fetched...

---

Ergänzung: Obiger Link funktioniert nicht mehr, [hier](http://www.weichei.info/) ist etwas vergleichbares, sogar mit doppelt so vielen Begriffen.

Comment: Das hatte ich schon total verdrängt :D +1 dafür

Comment: This is a perfect example on how useless link-only answers are in practice. Time has invalidated this one completely.

Answer (score 8):

I also suggest

> "Stell Dich nicht so an!"

Refer to meanings 9 and 10 in [the Wiktionary article for "anstellen"](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anstellen).

Comment: Ähnlich: *Hab dich nicht so*

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with:

> - Sei kein  Weichei
> - Sei kein Baby
> - Sei kein Feigling

Comment: "Heulsuse" is also used in the context of children knowing no other reaction than crying.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to *Weichei* you can also say

> Sei kein Waschlappen.

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waschlappen) says that this word (literally: *washing mitt*) can be used to describe a person with weak spirit. As far as I know, it's only used for men.

Comment: Correct, might be a bite dated, though.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest

> Heulsuse

as a translation for cry-baby.